# `fread`-ing text file with irregular separators

Tags: r, data.table

I need to read a large ( > 1GB) text file with irregular separators. A simplified example is the following:

> 1,1,1
>  1,1,1
>  ...
>  1,1,1,1
>  1,1,1
>  ...

The irregular lines (3 separators instead of 2 in the above example) show up possibly after the thousandth line.

`read.table` works with `fill=TRUE` and 4 values in `col.names`. `fread` with `fill=TRUE` fails to read the irregular lines. Adding `col.names` causes an error.

A MWE:

```
sometext  <-  "1,1,1"
fulltext  <-  paste(rep(sometext, 150), collapse="\n")
fulltext  <-  paste0(fulltext, "\n1,1,1,1") # Irregular line
fulltext  <-  paste0(fulltext, "\n1,1,1")

# Works
mwe.readtable  <- read.table(text=fulltext,
                            sep=",",
                            col.names = paste("V", 1:4, sep=""),
                            fill=TRUE)
# Fails w/ warning
mwe.fread  <- fread(fulltext,
                   sep =  ",",
                   fill=TRUE)

# Fails w/ error
mwe.fread2  <- fread(fulltext,
                   sep =  ",",
                   col.names = paste("V", 1:4, sep=""),
                   fill=TRUE)
```

Is there a way to prevent data.table from trying to guess the maximum number of separators?

Comment: Most efficient may be to use command line tools to count the max number of commas in any line in the file and then pad the rest of the lines.

Comment: There are two open issues which _may_ be relevant: [fread problem with different number of columns](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1812); [`fread` fails with uneven number of columns when max collumns in final row (with fill=TRUE and col.names set)](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2691)

Comment: @Gregor: Thank you for the suggestion. The data are sensitive and I am working remotely through a Windows server; I'm not familiar with the tools provided by that OS to deal with this type of problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `?fread` help in the 3rd paragraph says "'fread' is for _regular_ delimited files; i.e., where every row has the same number of columns." However, the fact that it has an option for `fill` contradicts that and if it's there you'd be right to expect it to work.  Besides the 2 issues  @Henrik noted, here is one other that indicates they may still be working on this issue: [fread breaks with incomplete lines and colClasses specified despite fill=TRUE #3054](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3a054)

Comment: It's possible with things like Cygwin to use `sed` or `awk` on Windows, or maybe install them directly? Don't know what's installed on your server. Powershell is what I've heard of as the Windows version of bash, but I've never used it before.

Comment: Try `iotools::read.csv.raw` using the `colClasses=` arg.